# Setting up virtual host on windows condeignitor

Tags: php, virtualhost, codeigniter-3, vhosts

I am trying to set up the virtual host for my app written in Codeignitor. Here is what I am doing

In my config.php file in codeignitor I do this

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://app.com';
```

Then in my hosts file I do this

```
127.0.0.1    www.myapp.com
127.0.0.1     api.myapp.com
127.0.0.1    files.myapp.com
```

Then in my vhosts file I add this code

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1> 
  DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost www.myapp> 
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp"
    ServerName myapp.com
    ServerAlias myapp.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\myApp">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I type http://www.myapp.com/ in my browser it gives me Access forbidden! error. Can I get some headers?

Answer (score -1):

Now it works. I a had to add .com in the VH files.